# Race condition in Rspec request test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a problem where I'm validating that the current time has been inserted into the html (used to do a sort of `time_ago` with javascript).

The current unix time (epoch) is rendered in the given html element's data data attribute, in this case like this:

```
<a href="/somewhere" data-last-points-awarded-at="1331606458">Something Happend</a>
```

But when my test runs:

```
recipe = Factory(:recipe, name: "Apple Pie", user: @user)

visit some_path

time_in_layout = find('a[data-last-points-awarded-at]')['data-last-points-awarded-at']
current_time = Proc.new { Time.now }.call.to_i.to_s

time_in_layout.should eql(current_time)
```

Upon running my test it fails... but just barely:

```
Failure/Error: time_in_layout.should eql(current_time)

   expected: "1331606459"
        got: "1331606458"

   (compared using eql?)
```

Everything is fine, the test is pretty much the way I actually want it to work however, the proc returns a time which is a second later, how can I fix this? Like how can I lock the time at the beginning of the test, can I even do such a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [TimeCop](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop), as it does exactly what you want.

Comment: This looks cool! but a whole gem for just one test? Is that overkill? It might be my only option.

Comment: You can only load it in the :test environment, but every gem does add a bit of load time, and messing with the Time class can lead to unanticipated consequences for other tests if you're not careful.

Comment: A better way would be to mock out the time before you make the call. That works better at the unit-test level, but if you test it at the unit level, then you can test for something else at the request level (like that a time is shown and it's within a reasonable range).